# getting filtered datas with sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a lot of datas and those have year column
I'd like to check if it has same data in a row as long as I set the start year and end year

if I set 2015 as start year and set 2017 as end year,
I have to get columns that have same data for 5 years

I tried to use `between` in my query but I can't even catch how should I do

the data looks like this

```
SELECT year,team,equip,result FROM my_table WHERE result = 41 AND year=2015
```

```
+------+-------+--------+--------+
| year | team  | equip  | result |
+------+-------+--------+--------+
| 2015 | teamA | equipA |   41   |
+------+-------+--------+--------+
| 2015 | teamA | equipB |   41   |
+------+-------+--------+--------+
| 2015 | teamB | equipA |   41   |
+------+-------+--------+--------+
| 2015 | teamB | equipB |   41   |
+------+-------+--------+--------+
| 2015 | teamC | equipA |   41   |
+------+-------+--------+--------+
| 2015 | teamC | equipB |   41   |
+------+-------+--------+--------+
...
```

```
SELECT year,team,equip,result FROM my_table WHERE result = 41 AND year=2016
```

```
+------+-------+--------+--------+
| year | team  | equip  | result |
+------+-------+--------+--------+
| 2016 | teamA | equipB |   41   |
+------+-------+--------+--------+
| 2016 | teamB | equipA |   41   |
+------+-------+--------+--------+
| 2016 | teamC | equipA |   41   |
+------+-------+--------+--------+
| 2016 | teamC | equipB |   41   |
+------+-------+--------+--------+
...
```

```
SELECT year,team,equip,result FROM my_table WHERE result = 41 AND year=2017
```

```
+------+-------+--------+--------+
| year | team  | equip  | result |
+------+-------+--------+--------+
| 2017 | teamA | equipA |   41   |
+------+-------+--------+--------+
| 2017 | teamB | equipA |   41   |
+------+-------+--------+--------+
| 2017 | teamB | equipB |   41   |
+------+-------+--------+--------+
| 2017 | teamC | equipA |   41   |
+------+-------+--------+--------+
...
```

What I want to get is this :

```
+-------+--------+--------+
| team  | equip  | result |
+-------+--------+--------+
| teamB | equipA |   41   |
+-------+--------+--------+
| teamC | equipA |   41   |
+-------+--------+--------+
...
```

I'd like to get columns that have same data for 3 years (2015~2017)

How can I do for this??

Comment: Do a GROUP BY, use HAVING to make sure all 3 years are there.

Comment: *if I set 2015 as start year and set 2017 as end year, I have to get columns that have same data for 5 years* I have calculated 3 times, and always the result was 3 years, not 5...

Answer (score 0):

I would use an aggregation approach here:

```sql
SELECT team, equip, MIN(result) AS result
FROM yourTable
WHERE year BETWEEN 2015 AND 2017
GROUP BY team, equip
HAVING MIN(result) = MAX(result) AND MIN(result) = 41;
```

Use this `HAVING` clause if there could be team/equip pairs which might not have data for all 3 years:

```
HAVING MIN(result) = MAX(result) AND MIN(result) = 41 AND
       COUNT(DISTINCT year) = 3
```

Comment: It seems `WHERE .. AND result = 41` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Do a `GROUP BY`. Use `HAVING` to make sure the result is the same for all 3 years.

```
SELECT team, equip, result
FROM tablename
WHERE year BETWEEN 2015 AND 2017
GROUP BY team, equip, result
HAVING count(distinct year) = 3
```